# Сделать метод асинхронным C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, .net-core

Нужно сделать метод асинхронным (чтобы он выполнялся во время того, как выполняются другие) и чтобы он начинал выполняться как только программа загрузится. Вот только я не понимаю как. Если в начале инициализации программы вызвать его как
`await Proc();`, то ругается, что не прописан async, который нельзя прописать в `MainWindow()` или `public partial class MainWindow : Window`. (Если что, метод постоянно проверяет наличие запущенного процесса в системе)

```
public Page3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Application.Current.MainWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Topmost = true;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
            ProcChecker();
        }


public async void ProcChecker()
        {
            while (checkeruseless)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("msedge"))
                    {
                        proc.Kill();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: покажите код, без кода толку нет.

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Answer (score 0):

Метод Task.Run() помог в решении